# How to connect and send a message to iOS device through bluetooth from a MacBook

Tags: python, ios, macos, bluetooth

How do you connect and send a message from a MacBook to an iOS device? Firstly, I set up a scanner using bleak. Reason for using bleak is that PyBluez and sockets didn't work as I did not have Python built with bluetooth. This is the scan code:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner


async def scan():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for d in devices:
        print(f"Device name: {d.name},\n",
              f"MAC address: {d.address},\n",
              f"Details: {d.details}\n")
```

I get a bunch of devices that are close to me, their names(which are usually `None`), identifier, CBPeripheral address, and status.

I've tried just simply connecting to it and sending a message, but to no avail.

```
address = "my_device_address"


async def main(address):
    async with BleakClient(address) as client:
        await client.connect()
        await client.write_gatt_char(0x000e, b'\x01\x00')

asyncio.run(main(address))
```

Any help is much appreciated: code, documentation, books, etc.